# how to connect tcpsocket to other computer

Tags: ruby, tcpsocket

- virtual os 1 using ubuntu with IP address 192.168.0.120 --client side
- virtual os 2 using ubuntu with IP address 192.168.0.121  --server side

code client side

```
require "socket"
client=TCP.open("192.168.0.120",2000)
puts "enter your message"
message=gets.chomp
client.write(message)
client.close
```

output on console

```
 Connection refused -connect(2) for "192.168.0.120" port 2000 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED
```

Comment: It looks like the client is connecting to itself, and there is nothing listening on port 2000. Are you sure that you've got correct ip addresses and that there is something listening?

Comment: thank you very much..i appreciate your help

Comment: Is there a reason you're coding the raw TCP/IP layer yourself, instead of using an existing TCP/IP framework such as iodine or EventMachine?

Comment: @Myst I do this for my assignment and I don't know about the TCP/IP framework

Comment: @feadrick , good luck  since this is an assignment, I would recommend that you start by testing your code on the same machine (using different port numbers) and later switch to different VMs. This allows you to isolate issues and easily distinguish between issues related to the environment/setup and issues related to your code.